# How to filter array php

Tags: php

I'm trying to get the bottom values of an array with a single condition as below :

Get all numeric values until the next value is a string then stop the instruction, and leave all other values even if they are numeric

```
<? php   $data= [1,2,3,'web',4,5,6,'web',7,8,9]; ?>
```

The output will be : 7,8,9

Comment: I don't understand the condition. It seems like your condition and output don't match. Could you reword or add another example so I can see exactly what you're trying to do?

Comment: run your array until the last integer value ??? something like this??

Comment: Hello, thanks for your feedback
my array contains 10 values for example : 1,2,3,web,4,5,6,web,7,8,9,10 i want the output to be 10,9,8,7.

Comment: Run your loop from bottom and check for each item ctype_digit method, if this returns true then continue otherwise exit the group.

Comment: now u have multiple solutions did u tried?

Comment: @Badrinath: not agreed with this, for suppose if OP ask 1,2,3 then we need to run from start????

Comment: Yes it did work thanks

Comment: @ahmedhendah: dont forgot to accept the correct answer this will help to future visitor, otherwise your question will be marked as open.

Comment: your question is still open, if answer solved your problem, just accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [array_reverse](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php) to get values from the array with elements in reverse order.

```
$reversed = array_reverse($data);
```

and then parse the array to stop where it gets a string

```
foreach($reversed as $value) {
    if(is_string($value)) {
      break;
    }
    $output[] = $value; 
}

//print_r($output); // to print the output array. This will return the values like 9, 8, 7

// do a reverse again to get the values in the format you want.

$final= array_reverse($output);

print_r($final); // to print the final array. This will return the values like 7, 8, 9
```

Here is a [DEMO](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7e1155d7e56aa74d7084ff9c1364dc35a87436b8)

Comment: Hello, its not working, the new array stills empty with no values

Comment: It's working fine if you check the demo link or send new array here so I can check whats not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, here i am storing values in to an array `$newArray` if value is integer. if string found in value just reset the array `$newArray`

```
<?php
$data = [1,2,3,'web',4,5,6,'web',7,8,9]; 
$newArray = array(); // resultant array
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    if(is_int($value)){
        $newArray[] = $value;
    }
    else{
        $newArray = array();    // reset if not integer
    }
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($newArray);
?>
```

[DEMO](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1ab6868b97ca3e998471eff0980c334c0642422e)

**Result:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 7
    [1] => 8
    [2] => 9
)
```

Now, you can use `implode()` for comma separated result, like:

```
echo implode(",",$newArray); // 7,8,9
```

**Edit: (08-07-2019)**

**If Example:**

```
$data = [1,2,3,'web',4,5,6,'web',7,8,9,'web'];
```

**Code:**

```
<?php
$data = [1,2,3,'web',4,5,6,'web',7,8,9,'web']; 
$newArray = array(); // resultant array

end($data);
$keyLast = key($data);  // fetches the key of the element pointed to by the internal pointer

foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    if(is_int($value) ){
        $newArray[] = $value;
    }
    else{
        if($keyLast === $key) { // if last key is string overwrite the previous array.
            $newArray = $newArray;
        }
        else{
            $newArray = array();    // reset if not integer
        }        
    }
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($newArray);
?>
```

**Edit:**

It's better to store all integer values into an array and then use `array_slice()` to get let three elements from new integer array like:

```
<?php
$data = [1,2,3,'web',4,5,6,'web',7,8,9,'web','web','web']; 
$newArray = array(); // resultant array
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    if(is_int($value) ){
        $newArray[] = $value;
    }    
}
$lastThreeElement = array_values(array_slice($newArray, -3, 3, true));
echo "<pre>";
print_r($lastThreeElement);
?>
```

Comment: This will give 1,2,3. For expected output you need to reverse it first.

Comment: @Badrinath: check DEMO link... i am doing reset the array if found an string

Comment: Hello, thanks this one worked for me

Comment: @ahmedhendah: glad to help u, dont forgot to accept the answer, this will help to future visitors.

Comment: Hello, what if my table as bellow :
     ``$data= [1,2,3,'web',4,5,6,'web',7,8,9,'web'];`` 
Then the output will be : **7,8,9**
And if the table as bellow : 
     ` $data= [1,2,3,'web',4,5,6,'web',7,8,9];`
The out put will be the same

Comment: @ahmedhendah: in both cases, you will get the desired output

Comment: @ahmedhendah: ohh u r right, let me share you solution

Comment: It is not working with the first condition  : `$data= [1,2,3,'web',4,5,6,'web',7,8,9,'web'];`
It gives me error

Comment: @ahmedhendah: yes u r right, let me share you updated code

Comment: Ok i'm waiting, thnx

Comment: @ahmedhendah: check edit

Comment: @devpro: yes it's working

Comment: @ahmedhendah: ok dont forgot to accept the answer by click on left hand side tick

Comment: @devpro: what if my table as bellow : $data = `[1,2,3,'web',4,5,6,'web',7,8,9,'web','web'];` , there is no output

Comment: @ahmedhendah: in this case , code will not work, becuase due to last 2 string indexes

Comment: What if i want to consider from 1 until 4 strings ?
`$data = [1,2,3,'web',4,5,6,'web',7,8,9];` output 7 8 9
`$data = [1,2,3,'web',4,5,6,'web',7,8,9,'web'];` output 7 8 9
`$data = [1,2,3,'web',4,5,6,'web',7,8,9,'web','web'];` output 7 8 9
`$data = [1,2,3,'web',4,5,6,'web',7,8,9,'web','web','web'];` outout 7 8 9
`$data = [1,2,3,'web',4,5,6,'web',7,8,9,'web','web','web','web'];` output 7 8 9

Comment: @ahmedhendah: its more complex

Comment: @ahmedhendah: i suggest you to store integer value into an array then pick the last three digit

Comment: @ahmedhendah: answer updated, please check EDIT

Answer (score 0):

We can try first filtering to find the first non numeric entry.  Then, subset the array starting with this index.  Finally, filter the subset again to remove all non numeric elements.

```
$data= [1,2,3,'web',4,5,6,'web',7,8,9];
$sub_data = array_filter($data, function($item) { return !is_numeric($item); });
$index = array_search(current($sub_data), $data);
$sub_data = array_slice($data, $index);
$sub_data = array_filter($sub_data, function($item) { return is_numeric($item); });
print_r($sub_data);
```

This prints:

```
Array
(
    [1] => 4
    [2] => 5
    [3] => 6
    [5] => 7
    [6] => 8
    [7] => 9
)
```

Answer (score 0):

i don't know if there a specific function for it but i got the same result with this

```
$data= [1,2,3,'web',4,5,6,'web',7,8,9];
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
  if($value=="web"){
    $x =$key;
  }
}
$data = array_slice($data,$x);
print_r($data);
```

Output:

```
Array ( [0] => web [1] => 7 [2] => 8 [3] => 9 )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just pop values off the end until you get to something that isn't an int.

```
while (is_int($n = array_pop($data))) {
    $result[] = $n;
}
```

This will modify the data array, so if you need to keep the original values, then do this with a copy.

Answer (score 0):

The test you'll want depends on whether your example data is representative and all the numeric values you want in the array are of type `int`, or perhaps some might be numeric strings.

```
$data= [1,2,3,'web',4,5,6,'web',7,8,9];
$result = [];
for($i = count($data)-1; $i >= 0; $i++) {
    // If some of the values you want might be numeric strings
    // (e.g. "7") or decimals (e.g. 1.5), use this
    if(!is_numeric($data[$i])) {
        break;
    }
    // If your values will only be integer type, use this
    if(!is_int($data[$i])) {
        break;
    }
    array_unshift($result,$data[$i]);
}

// If you want the results in original order
print_r($result);  // Output: [7,8,9]

// If you want the results inverted
$result = array_reverse($result);
print_r($result);  // Output: [9,8,7]
```